# Generating own key with Python Fernet

Tags: python-2.7, cryptography

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

import base64
# Put this somewhere safe!
key = Fernet.generate_key()

f = Fernet()
token = f.encrypt(b"A really secret message. Not for prying eyes.")
token
print f.decrypt(token)
```

How can I generate my own key instead of `fernet.genrate_key()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fernet a key can be generated using one of fernet's [Key Derivation Functions](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/key-derivation-functions/#module-cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf)

One of the functions provided by fernet is the 'Password Based Key Derivation Function 2'. 
An example that uses PBKDF2HMAC can be found at [Using Passwords with Fernet](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#using-passwords-with-fernet). This is discussed in [git issue #1333 of pyca/cryptography](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/1333#issuecomment-55481611), maebert points out that the example uses salt=os.urandom(16) and will generate a new key from a password each time the kdf class is constructed with a different salt value.

If you need to use a custom key derivation function look at source code for [kdf](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/_modules/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/#KeyDerivationFunction) 
and [pbkdf2](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/_modules/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/pbkdf2/#PBKDF2HMAC) 
to have an example of a class that implements the KeyDerivationFunction interface.

A class that matches its signature and implements the interface should be able to be dropped in as a custom key derivation function.

Answer (score 23):

The implementation shows how this is done:

```
return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(os.urandom(32))
```

So to generate your own you'll want to generate **32** cryptographically secure random bytes and then `urlsafe` base64 encode them. Of course, since `generate_key` already does this you should probably just call that unless you need to generate the key outside of your Python process.

Comment: Is it cryptographically safe? I mean its randomness (don't know how to phrase it).

Answer (score 8):

In Bash, you can do:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=32 count=1 2>/dev/null | openssl base64
```

*Source: [The Ruby implementation of Fernet](https://github.com/fernet/fernet-rb#generating-a-secret)*

Answer (score 5):

The python [Cyrptography Fernet documentation](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/) has a note on generating a secure key using a `password` and `salt`:

```
import base64
import os
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC

password = b"password"
salt = os.urandom(16)
kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
    algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
    length=32,
    salt=salt,
    iterations=390000,
)
key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password))
f = Fernet(key)
token = f.encrypt(b"Secret message!")
token
# b'...'
f.decrypt(token)
# b'Secret message!'
```

Note, the salt must be stored along with the passcode in order to re-generate the same key; which makes this feel a bit redundant, although it does add a layer of obfuscation. Its likely best just to use `Fernet.generate_key()` and store that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do this using a passcode, unsalted. Note this method does not generate a very secure key:

```py
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import base64, hashlib

def gen_fernet_key(passcode:bytes) -> bytes:
    assert isinstance(passcode, bytes)
    hlib = hashlib.md5()
    hlib.update(passcode)
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(hlib.hexdigest().encode('latin-1'))
```

Usage:

```py
passcode = '249524.405925.606329'
key = gen_fernet_key(passcode.encode('utf-8'))
fernet = Fernet(key)
data_in = "SOME DATA"
cypher_text = fernet.encrypt(data_in.encode('utf-8'))
decr_data = fernet.decrypt(cypher_text).decode('utf-8')

print(f"passcode: {passcode}")
print(f"data_in: {data_in}")
print(f"key: {key}")
print(f"cypher_text: {cypher_text}")
print(f"decr_data: {decr_data}")
```

Output:

```
passcode: 249524.405925.606329
data_in: SOME DATA
key: b'NWRmMTk3ZWUwY2RjNjA3NWY4NzQ2NmQyOGRkYzczMmM='
cypher_text: b'gAAAAABit-SGVb4JMb-AWCetN-T029YzxQBkRou3fQElSY0zidJbM7M5w5TeJzIacyMaFycmUxFPYrSDgDnOrhC0OggtJ_xDMw=='
decr_data: SOME DATA
```

Comment: encode('latin-1')? why this

Comment: @JAD - Because Base64 strings should always be in plain 7-bit ASCII, which should be 'latin-1'. bytes.encode() default of 'utf-8' would work fine but could be misleading to n00b's.